# Function doesn't work when called with addEventListener or onclick, doesn't show up any error msg

Tags: javascript, html, onclicklistener, addeventlistener

I wrote an easy function that should swap between 2 images, this function should fires when clicking on a button but nothing happens on click.

I've tried both addEventListener and onclick method but none in working.

```
<img id="avatar" src="dog1.jpg" alt="avatar">
<button id="button">change dog</button>
```

```js
    function changeDog() {
      var dog = document.getElementById('avatar').scr;
      if (dog == "dog1.jpg" ) {
        document.getElementById('avatar').scr = "dog2.jpg";
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById('avatar').src = "dog1.jpg";
      }
    }

    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.addEventListener=('click', changeDog);
```

I expect that clicking on the button the image with id='avatar' will change  source from "dog1.jpg" to "dog2.jpg" and viceversa, but absolutely nothing happens. No error msg is showed. I suspect it may be a dumb mistake cause I'm unexperienced, but I'm struck on this. Thank you all for any help.

Comment: `document.getElementById('avatar').scr` shouldn't it be `src`?

Comment: Also i'm quite sure it's `addEventListener()` , not `addEventListener=`

Comment: @LaurentS. You're wrong, it's `addEventListener`.

Comment: Why do you have a `=` before the parentheses?

Comment: @Baruch > fixed the typo, but the equal sign is still incorrect though...

Comment: @LaurentS. `addEventListener` is the correct way, but I'm not very sure about its declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code. For example, you have written `src` on some places, and `scr` on other. Also, you repeat the part of the code again and again.

```js
// Array with all dogs. Makes it easier to add more dogs.
const dogs = [ "dog1.jpg", "dog2.jpg" ];

function changeDog() {
  // Get the avatar element
  const avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');

  // Get current name. Note that the broswer probably have added
  // the full url to the image. I use split to break up the string
  // in an array, and then use slice(-1) to get the last item
  // and then [0] to get the element.
  const dog = avatar.src.split('/').slice(-1)[0];

  // get the index of the dog
  const index = dogs.indexOf( dog );

  // set the new src, from the dogs array, with the index + 1;
  // If index + 1 is larger than the length of the dogs-array
  // the % (remainder-operator) will make sure that the index
  // wraps around to 0, so we get the next name.
  avatar.src  = dogs[ ( index + 1 ) % dogs.length ];
  console.log( avatar.src );
}

var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', changeDog);
```

```html
<img id="avatar" src="dog1.jpg" alt="avatar">
<button id="button">change dog</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few typos in your code. See below

```js
function changeDog() {
  var dog = document.getElementById('avatar');
  
  if (dog.src === "dog1.jpg" ) {
    dog.src = "dog2.jpg";
  }
  else {
    dog.src = "dog1.jpg";
  }
}

 var button = document.getElementById('button');
 button.addEventListener('click', changeDog);
```

```html
<img id="avatar" src="dog1.jpg" alt="avatar">
<button id="button">change dog</button>
```

Also you should decide reading about comparision (using === instead of ==):
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeDog() {
  // you create a constant for document.getElementById().src, so do not need it every line
  const dog = document.getElementById('avatar').src;
  if (dog === "dog1.jpg" ) {
    dog = "dog2.jpg";
  }
  else {
    dog = "dog1.jpg";
  }
}    

const button= document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    changeDog();
}
```

Updated from var to let/const (new standard), changed your rough equate to an absolute and created a direct call toward the event listener, the call method I have used allows you to perform additional actions after `changeDog()` also if you so wish. Your original code had a few issues which prevented it from actually running.

Comment: Passing `changeDog` directly would work too; the problem with the OP code is that it wasn't actually calling `addEventListener()` at all. But your code would work too of course.

Comment: How is this differs from the Cofee bean answer except arrow function in addEventListener which has no effect on code?

Comment: yes well, I am truly sorry that he posted his answer while I was writing mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeDog() {
  const dog = document.getElementById('avatar');

  const imgSrc = dog.src === "dog1.jpg" ? "dog2.jpg" : dog.src;
  dog.src = imgSrc;
}

 const button = document.getElementById('button');
 button.addEventListener('click', changeDog);
```

```
<img id="avatar" src="dog1.jpg" alt="avatar">
<button id="button">change dog</button>
```